# Should you decorate dataclass subclasses if not making additional fields

Tags: python, conventions, python-dataclasses

If you don't add any more fields to your subclass is there a need to add the `@dataclass` decorator to it and would it do anything?

If there is no difference, which is the usual convention?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class AAA:
    x: str
    y: str
    
    ...

# decorate?
class BBB(AAA):
    ...
```

Comment: Have you tried it both ways? Could you tell any difference?

Comment: Not that I could see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation, `dataclasses` source code and experimenting with class instances, I don't see any difference, even if new fields are added to a subclass.

If we are talking conventions, then I would advise against decorating a subclass.  Class `BBB`'s definition is supposed to say *"this class behaves just like `AAA`, but with these changes"* (likely a couple of new methods in your case).

Re-decorating `BBB`:

- serves no purpose
- violates DRY principle: although it's just one line, but still there's no particular difference between re-decorating and copy-pasting a short method from superclass
- could (potentially) get in the way of changing `AAA`: you might theoretically switch to another library for dataclassing or decide to use `@dataclass` with non-default parameters, and that'd require maintaining subclass as well (for no good reason).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't decorate your class, the variables defined in the root of the class will be `class attributes` which would be shared between all instances of the class. The `dataclass` let's you define the variables there but they would be `instance attributes` so each instance can hold its own value. If you instantiate only a single object, you won't see the difference.

**UPDATE**

Misunderstood your question. The decorate "adds" a few methods to your class, such as `__init__` and `__repr__`. If you're not adding any attributes to your child class, then adding the decorator just instructs the interpreter to go through the MRO to update the mapping, which hasn't changed. It will not cause any trouble, it's just unnecessary. I haven't seen any well-defined convention for it but I wouldn't do it.

Comment: I'm not asking about whether or not to decorate base class A (it will be decorated as a dataclass). But about any of its subclasses